# How can I access a variable from Global.asax in a webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a small method in each of my asp.net pages which logs user statistics in the database. I have just added two methods to the Global.asax to capture the load time of the page but I would also like to be able to access that result on the individual pages code-behind so I can log it during page load along with the other information.

This is the code from my Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context.Items["loadstarttime"] = DateTime.Now;
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime end = (DateTime)Context.Items["loadstarttime"];
    TimeSpan loadtime = DateTime.Now - end;
    Response.Write("<br/><br/><br/><h3>This page took " + loadtime + "ms to load</h3>");
}
```

Comment: The web-form has access to `Context`, no?

Comment: Simplest should be to make context public static accessible.

Comment: So how do I get the end load time before the page unload?

Comment: If Context IS the [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx) the webform has access to the [Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.context(v=vs.110).aspx) because every webform derives from the `Page` class.

Comment: @rene Yes but I need to find the end of the page generation time. The application endrequest fires after the page unload. If you could provide an example it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the Page Life Cycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx you'll need to get have that measurement ready at the end of `Render` method of the Page. Beyond that the outputstream can no longer be written to.

Comment: @rene But I'm sure it's not possible. If I can only take the measurement after unload, I don't know how I will get it during render?

Comment: @connersz - the answer is that you can't.  It's impossible.  The best you can do is get the time of when the page is *almost* done rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with getting the total processing time as you do in your question AND getting it rendered in the page at the correct moment is impossible to achieve.

By the time you have your final time the stream that sends the bytes to the client are long gone and there is no way to add anything to it.

So your only option to get something properly rendered within the html is to add a control to your page with as it's main task to render how long it took from `BeginRequest` to the moment that specific control was rendered.

That control looks like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Time : Control
    {
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            // no error checking whatsoever! Add that before using!
            writer.Write("<h3>render time: {0}</h3>", 
                         DateTime.Now - (DateTime)Context.Items["loadstarttime"]);
        }
    }
}
```

and I placed it on a page like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="plain.aspx.cs" Inherits="plain" %>
<%@ Register tagPrefix="my" namespace="MyNamespace" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    .. removed stuff ...
    <my:Time runat="server"></my:Time>
</body>
</html>
```

This will render just before the closing tags are send to the output stream.

Now you can make it render one little bit later but to be html compliant you need to render a comment. You could do that from the overrriding the `Render` method on the page:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
    writer.Write("<!-- render time {0} -->", DateTime.Now - (DateTime)Context.Items["loadstarttime"]);
}
```

That would give you this html output in the client:

```
    ...
    <h3>render time: 00:00:01.9361936</h3>
</body>
</html>
<!-- render time 00:00:01.9381938 -->
```

After the Render method `Unload` takes place in the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) and the note on that page for Unload says:

> During the unload stage, the page and its controls have been rendered, so you cannot make further changes to the response stream. If you attempt to call a method such as the Response.Write method, the page will throw an exception.

What you could do if you're really interested in total request times is to store it and use it the next time the page is rendered (or calculate an average). You can then render something like:

> `Last processing time   : 0.2333`
>    `average processing time: 0.15`

by collecting these statistics in the `EndRequest` but you cann't include the result for the currentpage.

Have a look at [`Tracing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08(v=vs.100).aspx) for a developer oriented view on performance and page structure.

Answer (score -1):

[Page.Context Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.context(v=vs.110).aspx) gets the [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) object associated with the page, for example:

```
public partial class DefaultPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        var val = Context.Items[key];
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

}
```

**Update**

Since [Page Unload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.unload(v=vs.85).aspx) event occurs **before** [HttpApplication EndRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event you could consider the following approach:

Global.asax.cs:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Context.Items.Remove("AfterPageUnloaded");
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pageUnloaded = Context.Items.Contains("AfterPageUnloaded") && (bool)Context.Items["AfterPageUnloaded"];
        if (pageUnloaded)
        {
            //Your code goes here..
            Context.Items.Remove("AfterPageUnloaded");
        }
    }
}
```

Page class

```
public partial class DefaultPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        Context.Items["AfterPageUnloaded"] = true;
        base.OnUnload(e);
    }
}
```